# Cache Manifest File (name.appcache) not linked to gsp Page

Tags: html, grails, html5-appcache

My goal is to store resources and html pages using appcache or manifest file for offline usage for a grails app. For that we are using manifest attribute inside  tag and are trying to link it to our cache manifest file. We followed these steps to use appcache inside html page:

1)- Added MIME type inside our config.groovy file

grails.mime.types = [ 
  appcache: 'text/cache-manifest' 
 ]

2)- Added manifest attribute inside html tag on that page which we need to cached.
  
    My html page says (name.gsp) and name.appcache both are in same directory location.

3)- Inside name.appcache file we included resources (Javascript files,video links) which are being used by that page:
     our cache manifest file which is linked by this page is shown below:

```
 CACHE MANIFEST
```

# 28-05-02015

CACHE:

/assets/googleAnalytics.js

/assets/cptTest/smoother.js

/assets/cptTest/compatibility.js

/assets/cptTest/objectdetect.js"

/assets/cptTest/js_object_detect_test.js

/assets/cptTest/objectdetect_frontalface.js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/es7g1ii56j

Problem:
      The problem which we are now facing is that our manifest file is not being picked successfully to that page where it is being used. When we use window.applicationCache object        on page load function of name.gsp to check status of application cache it always gives us status NOT CACHED or simple "UNCACHED".

So can anyone please tell me how can we reference cache manifest file to my html/gsp page inside grails application? As we have adopted the above mentioned procedure which is suggested by most of developer but we are still getting UNCACHED status ?